# PhpStorm Marks Existing Variable as "Unresolved Variable"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phpstorm

I am working with `AngularJS` in PhpStorm. I am new to both.
I have two files in my project, `index.html` and `app.js`. From `index.html`, I am referencing a variable `store.products` defined in `app.js`, but PhpStorm tells me that it cannot resolve the variable.

PhpStorm has no problems with `product.name`.

The code works without problems in the browser, so I figured something must be wrong with the editor. Or maybe the error is just a subtle one that the browser simply ignores.

`index.html` (the problem is in the ng-repeat directive):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
<head lang="en">
  (...)
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
      <h3>
        {{product.name}}
      </h3>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js`:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.products = gems;
  });

  var gems = [
    ...
  ];

})();
```

I was hoping someone could spot the error. Even though the page renders correctly in the browser, it is pretty annoying that PhpStorm displays the error.

**Edit:** In `app.js`, `this.products` is not marked with `"unused definition: products"` when I reference `store.products` from `index.html`. So somehow PhpStorm can see that the variable is being used, but still can't see it from `index.html`'s point of view.

Comment: +1 for AngularJS with PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PhpStorm should be able to find the reference. I just tested it here and works with my PhpStorm.

```
<html ng-app="store">
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store"> <-- store is already app name.
```

You've named the controller alias and your app the same keyword `store`. I think this is confusing PhpStorm. Try giving the controller a different alias.

If that still doesn't work, then try this:

Start PhpStorm, click menu "File / Invalidate Cache" and select "Invalidate and Restart".

Comment: I tried renaming my app (since that's obviously a bad choice of name -- thanks) and then invalidating the cache. However, the problem remains the same. I also tried creating a new project with no luck.

Comment: @MathiasBrandt what build of PhpStorm are you using?

Comment: I am using PhpStorm 8.0.1 build #PS-138.2001.

Comment: @MathiasBrandt and you have plugin AngularJS ver 138.1988?

Comment: Yes, I just installed everything today :)
I have tried continuing with the tutorial I am following. Defining a new controller poses even more problems. PhpStorm does not see the entire new controller. I suspect something fundamental is wrong in my app.js ...

Comment: @MathiasBrandt you could try going to Settings/Plugins and select show:Custom. Disable everything except AngularJS. See if that helps, but at this point I'm guessing.

Comment: I have no other plugins than AngularJS when show:Custom is selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61970/discussion-between-mathias-brandt-and-mathew-foscarini).

Answer (score 0):

I can recreate the issue in PHPStorm 8/WebStorm 9 EAP. The problem is that Angular plugin doesn't correctly recognize Angular 1.2 'as' syntax. Please vote for [WEB-11544](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11544)